# jQuery tablesorter, staticwidget and sortList together?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I cannot figure out why the two will not work together.
I have a table that sorts just fine with table sorter. I have styled the rows to look more like nice divs and needed a space between each row. I do this with an empty  with a CSS class, then apply the 'static' widget as well. This all works great, when sorting, those invisible spacing rows stay put.

The problem arises when I try to also set a default sortList. I've tried the different code below; trying to set it in javascript and as metadata. The two simply won't work together. I can get sortList to work just fine, as long as I disable the static widget. But when they are together, the rows are static, but stacked together and out of the sort order.

Can anyone help me figure out a way to have the static widget and sortList to work together? Thank you!

(I have jQuery 2.14, tablesorter, staticRow widget and metadata .js's loaded in the html head)

It won't work together this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#myTable').tablesorter({
        widgets: ['staticRow'],
        sortList: [[0,0]]
    });
} );
```

But does work with either alone:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#myTable').tablesorter({
        widgets: ['staticRow']
    });
} );
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#myTable').tablesorter({
        sortList: [[0,0]]
    });
} );
```

Also tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#myTable').tablesorter({
        widgets: ['staticRow']
    });
} );

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter {sortlist: [[0,0],[4,0]]}">
```

Comment: Can you please make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can investigate the problem?

Comment: I've tried, but I have never used it before and cannot figure out how to attach the js required. I cannot find a url to the tablesorter version I am using. (I am not using the forked version)

Comment: if there is not an online version of it, you can simply copy and paste it in the JavaScript section.

Comment: Thank you. Working on it right now

Comment: Okay, here we go. As it is right now, I have the "sorting" commented out on **line 15**. The table sorts correctly, while basically ignoring the <tr>s with a 'static' class. However, once you uncomment **line 15** you can see how the tablesorter treats the static rows. They are still static, but not a part of the sort. In my more complex script, sometimes these empty rows are filtered into random sequences with the real data... Thank you!  https://jsfiddle.net/ku7a3pcx/6/

Comment: What is `staticRow widget` supposed to do exactly?

Comment: Thank you for your help EhsanT, I got the answer below. The staticRow widget just keeps the row in place that contains the class of "static". It allows my table to look more like a series of styled divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that tablesorter is sorting the table before the widget is applied. So, the widget is setting the row indexes after the sort. If you have a small table, the easiest solution would be to trigger the sort after tablesorter has initialzied ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1799/))

```
$('#myTable')
  .tablesorter({
    widgets: ['staticRow']
   })
   .trigger("sorton", [[[0,0]]]);
```

If you have a larger table, more time will be needed before initialization. In this case, add the `trigger` inside a `setTimeout`.

---

Update: You can prevent quicksearch from hiding all static rows using this code:

```
$('input#search').quicksearch('table tbody tr', {
  hide: function(){
    this.style.display = $(this).hasClass('static') ? "table-row": "none";
  }
});
```

But you'll end up with some really big gaps ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ku7a3pcx/13/)).

To fix this you'll need to include some css; you'll need to use an `!important` flag to override the inline style ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ku7a3pcx/14/)).

```
tr[style*="display: none"] + tr.VerticalSpacer {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you help with one more problem? On this fiddle I added my quicksearch feature....problem here is that if you were to type "e" in the search field the "static" rows are removed. My javascript is obviously limited. Thank you for your help! https://jsfiddle.net/ku7a3pcx/9/